# Regex for text between a set of chars

Tags: regex

I have been trying to get a string between two other strings.  For example, The full string is;

```
"main.aspx?etc=2&id=c3331316-1b17-e811-a953-0022480042b3&Key=930349624&Window=true"
```

And I am trying to get the string between "id=" and "&";

```
"c3331316-1b17-e811-a953-0022480042b3"
```

The regex I have landed on is;

```
id=(.*?)&
```

My regex attempts are including the "id=" and the "&". So they are coming out like this;

```
"id=c3331316-1b17-e811-a953-0022480042b3&"
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated as from what I have read this should be working. The regex is being supplied by me and run through a third party software piece so I want to find out if I am wrong or the software is.  I'd imagine I am :-)

Comment: What is your target lang / tool?

Comment: Use lookarounds, if the language support them

Comment: your regex works, the string you want is into your first group  have a look here: https://regex101.com/r/FCMM2s/3

Comment: All the answers (other than the one I gave), accept anything where the last letters of a parameter are `id`. i.e. `hid=true` will match and `otherid=hekwe9384` will match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a matching group. Do not try to get the whole result, but only the grouped result.

Though, you can use lookahead and lookbehind groupings, like this :

```
(?<=id=)(.*?)(?=&)
```

Edit, if the `id` parameter is the last in the URL, the regex won't trigger. You can use this regular expression if you are unsure of its place within the URL :

```
(?<=(?:\?|&)id=)(.*?)(?=&|$)
```

Comment: be careful with this solution.  If the id=... is at the end of the url there won't be another & to anchor it and the result will not be returned.

Comment: Right, you can replace `&` with `&|$`. Thanks for pointing that out. I edited my answer.

Comment: This will also match `main.aspx?etc=2&Key=930349624&Window=true&otherid=c3331316-1b17-e811-a953-0022480042b3`, meaning it is not simply taking the actual `id` parameter

Answer (score 0):

The * greedily takes the & until it finds the last one in the string. 
Try this.

`id=([^&]+)`

As @revo pointed out this, this will match and return the entire id=... parameter. The ( ) captures the value portion into a separate matches value.  This is usually represented as an array or hash of some sort dependent on your programming language.

```
(?<=id=)[^&]+
```

Revo's modification will match and return the value of id without having to use capturing backreferences.

Both have the added benefit of not having to have a & at the end of the parameter. Meaning both of these urls will be matched.

"main.aspx?etc=2&**id=c3331316-1b17-e811-a953-0022480042b3**&Key=930349624&Window=true"

"main.aspx?etc=2&Key=930349624&Window=true&**id=c3331316-1b17-e811-a953-0022480042b3**"

Comment: It's better to consider last edit. That works this wouldn't.

Comment: I see your point @revo.  The OP used capturing parentheses in his post so I assumed he was comfortable with that concept.   This will work as it captures the value portion into the first match.

Comment: He used capturing group and said this whole thing will capture delimiters too which are not desired. Your solution only omits `&` in result but `id=` still exists.

Comment: This will also match `main.aspx?etc=2&Key=930349624&Window=true&otherid=c3331316-1b17-e811-a953-0022480042b3`, meaning it is not simply taking the actual `id` parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
[?&]id=(.*?)(?:&|$)
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rwzr7J/1)

What all other answers here fail to do is **not** match something in the form:

```
main.aspx?otherid=hek83749dbidne3
```

This regex will make sure that the `id` either appears directly after the `?` or after an ampersand.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
(?<=id=)(.*?)(?=&)
```

This will match everythink between "id=" and "&"

Comment: You don't need to escape `i` and `&`.

Comment: Yes - I can confirm that this returned a blank space, whilst removing the slashes worked.

Comment: Feel free to remove capturing group too.

Comment: This will also match `main.aspx?etc=2&Key=930349624&Window=true&otherid=c3331316-1b17-e811-a953-0022480042b3`, meaning it is not simply taking the actual `id` parameter